# Defining a Nested Tree (set-theoretic)

Tags: set-theory, trees, cantor-set

I am new to the world of trees and I am trying to make a painless addition to this general definition:

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathfrak{T}$ be a collection of sets.

$(\mathfrak{T},\prec)$ is a $tree$ if

(1) $\prec$ is a strict partial order on $\mathfrak{T}$

(2) $\forall x,y\in \mathfrak{T}, \{x\in \mathfrak{T}:x\prec y\}$ is  well-ordered by $\prec$

A $tree$ $in$ $X$ is a function $f:\mathfrak{T}\rightarrow X$.

I would now like to add a condition that the elements of $\mathfrak{T}$ are nested, when they are related, with the minimum of machinery.

Basically, I am looking for a graceful transition from the definition of general tree to more specific Cantor set construction, which I will present as a "nested interval tree", still working on the name. Is there a good definition of a nested tree out there that might fit the bill?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29

Comment: In general it doesn't make much sense to say that the nodes of a tree are nested, but if your nodes are sets (e.g. sets of reals as in your Cantor set example) then you could simply say that $x\subseteq y$ whenever $y\prec x$ are nodes of $\mathfrak{T}$.

Comment: Perhaps the term _laminar family_ might be useful to you.